# pandas create category column based on sequence repetition in another column

Tags: python, pandas

This is very likely a duplicate, but I'm not sure what to search for to find it.

I have a column in a dataframe that cycles from 0 to some value a number of times (in my example it cycles to 4 three times) . I want to create another column that simply shows which cycle it is. Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4]})

df['desired_output'] = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]

print(df)

    A  desired_output
0   0               0
1   1               0
2   2               0
3   3               0
4   4               0
5   0               1
6   1               1
7   2               1
8   3               1
9   4               1
10  0               2
11  1               2
12  2               2
13  3               2
14  4               2
```

I was thinking maybe something along the lines of a `groupby()`, `cumsum()` and `transform()`, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it. Could be wrong though.

Comment: Is possible first value is not `0` ? Then what is expected output?

Comment: ...yeah... what'd happen given (if it can happen): `[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 0, 3, 4, 5]` etc...

Comment: I want the same result. I just wanted to count the sequence number, so if it started on 0 it would still be in sequence 1 (or sequence 0, whichever you want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare by `0` with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and then add [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), last subtract `1`:

```
df['desired_output'] = df['A'].eq(0).cumsum() - 1
print (df)
    A  desired_output
0   0               0
1   1               0
2   2               0
3   3               0
4   4               0
5   0               1
6   1               1
7   2               1
8   3               1
9   4               1
10  0               2
11  1               2
12  2               2
13  3               2
14  4               2
```